# Probability of getting an Ace or a Spade (in any order) when cards are drawn with replacement?

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm trying to study for my statistics final by looking over the exams we've taken this semester and I can't quite figure out what I did wrong here. The question is: Two cards are randomly drawn from a well-shuffled standard deck
a. What is the probability of getting an Ace and a Spade (in any order) when the cards are drawn WITH REPLACEMENT?
My answer was $\frac{4}{52} * \frac{13}{52} $
I got a point taken off for this for some reason (2 point question). I don't really understand why? The question is with replacement, so the probability of drawing an ace would be 4/52 and the probability of drawing a spade would be 13/52. What am I missing?

Comment: You found the probability that the first card is an ace and the second card is a spade, but there are other ways to draw an ace and a spade.

Comment: Clarifying question: does drawing, say an ace of spades, then a 10 of hearts count?

Comment: It looks like your count includes the Ace of Spades  being paired with itself - not possible.

Comment: @herbsteinberg - the question says "with replacement"

Comment: Title says ace OR spade, but text says ace AND spade.  My reply assumes AND.

Answer (score 1):

The question looks fuzzy, but my take is as follows: Three cases.

$P_1=\frac{1}{52}\times\frac{16}{52}$ - first card is ace of spades.

$P_2=\frac{3}{52}\times\frac{13}{52}$ - first card is other ace.

$P_3=\frac{12}{52}\times\frac{4}{52}$ - first card is other spade.

Total $P_1+P_2+P_3=\frac{103}{2704}$